# 1 graphics card, with 2 outputs and 3 monitors

Tags: display, nvidia-geforce

i'm about to upgrade my home office with an aditional 2 monitors.
so i will have a total of 3. The problem is my GFX card only have 2 outputs, it is a ASUS GeForce GTX 275 896MB PhysX CUDA.
Now i only want to run movies and webpages on the monitors so it is nothing demanding. So what should i do? buy an addition graphics card to my computer? Or can i in someway make 2 monitors use the same DVI port?
Edit: Will i get any problems if i added another gfx card, say ASUS GeF GT210, not SLI'ed ofcause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do you want to have the computer stretch the output to display on all 3 monitors at once** (e.g. one desktop on 3 different monitors)? If so, you will probably need to get a new graphics card so that you have 3 DVI ports available. Your current one should be able to handle 3 monitors at once, so your additional card probably does not have to be very powerful (buy a cheapo one just for the port) because your powerful one can do most of the rendering. If you don't have another port on the motherboard for an additional graphics card then you will have to get a new motherboard.

**If you want to display the same desktop 3 different times on each monitor**, then I think you would be safe just to buy a DVI-splitter adapter/cable. I haven't attempted any of this, but after a bit of research I think this is what will be necessary for each scenario. Best of luck!

Comment: It is the first "Do you want to have the computer stretch the output to display on all 3 monitors at once", but to have the powerfull do the work for the cheepo gfx card will i have to SLI them? or will it automatic figure it out? The graphis card i was thinking of bying is ASUS GEFORCE GT 210 512MB DDR2 (only $69)

Comment: I believe SLI only works between two (usually high end) graphics cards, so either your current one is already functioning as two graphics cards or you already have two graphics cards (assuming the latter). If you install a third one, then the computer should automatically configure everything so long as they each have their own pci slot. As always I would suggest a bit of research on your part about this if you haven't already done so just to double check. Check out the wiki on SLI to see if that helps any: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Link_Interface